# MacBook Pro 2016 struggling with VM and unable to install dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox, macbook, macosx

so my problem is. I am going to do some machine learning at my Uni this semester and we were told to install Ubuntu 16.04.3. I have never worked with Ubuntu or Linux, however I spent quite some time during past week trying to get it work on my 2016 MacBook Pro (13 inch, 16GB RAM, 2.9GHz dual core i5, 256GB SSD, Intel Iris Graphics 550).

First of all, I installed it using VirtualBox, following the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qACZ0A8jK-s&feature=youtu.be&t=1024) that our teacher provided us with. I dedicated 8GB of RAM out of 16 to the VM, maximised video memory that it can use and enabled 3D acceleration and the VM was running very laggy and slow. So I did some research and tried dedicating only 4GB of RAM to it to put less pressure on host OS, but it was still no better.

Then I decided to install it as dual boot in order to use full power of my laptop. For this I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQIaDO9nR6Y&t=1s), but I ran into problem when during installation process of Ubuntu I should choose which partition Ubuntu should use. The problem here is that I can't see my main SSD, it only shows me the bootable USB drive that I'm running the installation from. I tried various ways of creating bootable USB (through terminal and also through the program provided by the guy who made the tutorial) and also tried 2 different USB drives but still the same problem. I'm using regular 'old fashioned' USB 3.0 drives connected via USB-C hub. Could this cause some problems and should I rather go and buy USB-C drive that I can connect directly to the laptop or is it pointless? Or does anybody have idea what could cause this issue?

I know that these laptops and not very friendly with Linux and I was told that I could use PyCharm and Python 3.5 in OS X in the beginning but I will most probably be required to use Ubuntu later into semester.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue with Virtual machine by using Parallels Desktop Lite instead of VirtualBox. It runs very smooth now. I will keep looking into dualboot issue.